# How can I set a maximum vmax in a scatterplot that uses normalized KDE values?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When trying to find a maximum range within a set of dataframes (which is represented by the integer variable `maxer`), I cannot create a standardized range of scatterplot points and their corresponding colors.

I want each plot to have a maximum that is the highest number seen in all of the dataframes. I would also like this range to be applied to the dataframes with maximums that are not so high, but I fail in doing so because they take on the brightest color, which should not be the case.

So I would like the scatter plot points and the color bar to both have the same range, from 0 to `maxer`.
I also need the KDE clustering to stay in because it does not look pretty without it.

```py
from matplotlib import colors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

# Calculate the maximum conflicts across all data frames
maxer = 0
for i, (name, df) in enumerate(my_dfs_p2v.items()):
    
    # Group by 'conflict_x' and 'conflict_y' and calculate the average frequency for each coordinate
    grouped_df = df.groupby(['conflict_x', 'conflict_y']).size().reset_index(name='frequency')
    
    # Calculate the actual number of conflicts for each coordinate
    actual_conflicts = grouped_df['frequency']
    if actual_conflicts.max() > maxer:
        maxer = actual_conflicts.max()

for i, (name, df) in enumerate(my_dfs_p2v.items()):
    plt.figure(figsize=(7, 5))    
    # Group by 'conflict_x' and 'conflict_y' and calculate the average frequency for each coordinate
    grouped_df = df.groupby(['conflict_x', 'conflict_y']).size().reset_index(name='frequency')
    
    # Calculate the actual number of conflicts for each coordinate
    actual_conflicts = grouped_df['frequency']
    
    # Use kernel density estimation (KDE) to estimate the density of conflicts
    kde = gaussian_kde([grouped_df['conflict_x'], grouped_df['conflict_y']])
    
    # Evaluate the KDE only for the unique coordinates
    kde_values = kde([grouped_df['conflict_x'], grouped_df['conflict_y']])
    
    # Normalize the KDE values to the range of actual_conflicts for color intensity
    norm_kde_values = colors.Normalize(vmin=actual_conflicts.min(), vmax=actual_conflicts.max())(kde_values)
    
    # Normalize the actual number of conflicts to the range of [0, 1] for color intensity
    norm_actual_conflicts = colors.Normalize(vmin=actual_conflicts.min(), vmax=actual_conflicts.max())(actual_conflicts)
    norm_actual_conflicts = norm_actual_conflicts.compressed()  # Convert to regular numpy array
    
    # Create a scatter plot of conflicts with scaled color intensity
    plt.scatter(grouped_df['conflict_x'], 960 - grouped_df['conflict_y'], s=100, c=norm_kde_values, cmap='viridis', alpha=0.7)
    
    # ...irrelevant code that puts a background picture goes here...

    # Adjust the axes and figure properties to match the image dimensions
    plt.xlim(0, 1280)
    plt.ylim(0, 960)
    plt.title(f'Conflicts for {name}')
    
    # Create a ScalarMappable object using 'viridis' colormap
    scalar_mappable = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='viridis', norm=colors.Normalize(vmin=actual_conflicts.min(), vmax=actual_conflicts.max()))
    scalar_mappable.set_array(norm_kde_values)
    
    # Add a colorbar to indicate the density of conflicts using the 'viridis' colormap
    cbar = plt.colorbar(scalar_mappable)
    cbar.set_label('Density of Conflicts')
    
    # Show the plot
    plt.show()
```

I tried putting `vmax=maxer` into various lines such as in the colors.Normalize line, but it fails as it just creates a new range from 0 to the maximum found in the dataframe. I want the maximum across ALL dataframes, in order to create a standardized range.

[image: Saturday plot] [image: Sunday plot]

Sunday should be following Saturday's range and it should have mostly darker colors, see the range on the colorbar? But it doesn't

Comment: It's `max_in_columns = max((max(df['column']) for df in set_of_dataframes))` or there is something that I do not understand.

Comment: @gboffi yes, that looks like a simplified way to find `maxer`, but the question is how to make each plot have a standardized color range, with the maximum being `maxer`. When I do manage to set a standardized color range, the scatter plot points are inflated to match the range, which misrepresents the data. I want to keep KDE clustering and I want to keep the original frequency values.

Comment: _"the scatter plot points are inflated to match the range"_ ፨ Sorry, I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I'm sorry I don't speak Pandas, so my suggestion is woven using Numpy and Matplotlib only. I think it's rather trivial to adapt to your preferred libraries - otoh, I've used `recarray`s that are superficially similar to dataframes.

The key points in the code below:

1. find the min/max across all your data instances, and instantiate a single `Normalize` object, specifying the min/max that you've found for ALL of the data (maybe you prefer to set the minimum identically equal to zero),
2. use the same `Normalize` object to color all of your scatter plots.

Note that you must first place the colorbar using space from the last column of subplots, and only later procede to remove the unused Axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 120
plt.rcParams['figure.constrained_layout.use'] = True

np.random.seed(20230801)

N  = 60
x  = np.random.rand(N)
y  = np.random.rand(N)
z0 = np.random.rand(N)

Z = np.rec.fromarrays(
    [z0+d for d in np.linspace(1, 3, 7)],
    names = 'Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat'.split())

Zmax = round(max((max(z) for z in Z)))
Zmin = round(min((min(z) for z in Z)))

########### H E R E   I T   IS  our single norm   
norm = plt.Normalize(Zmin, Zmax)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 4, figsize=(9, 4), edgecolor='k', linewidth=0.5)
fig.suptitle('The days of the week are different')

for ax, name in zip(axs.flatten(), Z.dtype.names):
    ax.set_title(name)
    ############  A N D   H E R E   I T S   U S A G E
    scat = ax.scatter(x, y, c=Z[name], norm=norm, ec='k', lw=0.5)
cb = fig.colorbar(scat, ax=axs[:3])
cb.set_label('Bla bla')
axs[1, 3].remove()

plt.show()
```